# Why was my answer about the Simpsons and Futurama belonging to different universes deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

Someone asked whether [Springfield still existed in Futurama's future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19662/does-springfield-still-exist-in-the-futurama-future).

I [answered that it didn't](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19665/770), since the Simpsons don't belong in the same universe at all (hint: different color skin!).

However, my answer was deleted by a moderator. Why? My answer makes sense (I'm not claiming I am right; merely that it's an acceptable & on-topic answer, with a justification), and in fact, [someone else answered the same thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19671/770), which wasn't deleted.

Someone else [making the same point](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19704/770), which wasn't deleted either.

So, why was my answer deleted?

Comment: Thanks to whoever undeleted my answer!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why your answer was deleted, it does make about as much sense as one can expect considering the rather poor question. I've restored it.

In our collective defense, due to the [traffic spike from *Futurama* questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/please-have-introductory-material-on-the-answerama-front-page/1983#1983), we (collectively, I'm afraid I didn't quite pull my weight because I arrived on the scene the rush was already abating) handled about as many flags within the space of a couple of hours yesterday as we normally do in a month. *Futurama* questions are especially difficult to moderate because what looks like a convoluted, preposterous, made-up-on-the-spot theory may well be the exact plot of the show. Please don't hesitate to contact us if we missed something.

Comment: ... That second to last sentence is just excellent.

Answer (score 3):

I am the one who deleted it.

I was helping out during the answeramocalypse, and deleted several non-answers. In my eyes, your question belonged (and to be honest, still belongs) in that category, but I'm not as familiar with the scifi.se community as you are, so I may have misjudged here. If the communtiy thinks this answer is okay, I'm the last to argue with that. I apologize.

Comment: The *question* is a silly one, but we have a tradition of allowing “are gorillas and sharks in the same universe” questions :(. The answer is correct if partial, which put it in the upper 90% of Anseramocalypse answers right there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: I didn't realize my answer sounded off-topic. I've reworded it to make it explicitly on-topic. By the way, I understand your pain at the "answeramocalypse" -- then again, I think most marketing attempts by the CHAOS or StackExchange staff or whatever they are called are misguided and usually backfire. But I'm cynical at most marketing attempts anyway ;)

Comment: @Gilles I wouldn't have protested closing the question itself, and in fact, I still think it's a good candidate for closing!